# Concatenation between two columns in SQL query with Urdu text is not working?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Query

```
declare @string  nvarchar='والد'

SELECT   sCustomerNameUrdu +' '+ @string +' '+sFatherNameUrdu from Customer
```

**it give me**

Column1 ??? column2

e.g

علی ??? سیعد

**but Desired Out Put is**

Column1 والد column2

e.g

علی والد سیعد

Comment: is this MySql or Sql Server? please tag appropriately

Comment: Does `SELECT sCustomerNameUrdu +' '+ @string +' '+sFatherNameUrdu, @string, ' '+ @string +' ' from Customer` look like expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you have declared `@string` as `nvarchar`, you are not setting the *value* to a [unicode string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx). Therefore it is creating it as an ascii value, which messes it up, and then stores the result of that in the unicode variable.

Also give the variable a size, otherwise it will default to 1 character.

This should work (note the `N` in front of the string):

```
declare @string nvarchar(50)
set @string = N'والد';

SELECT   sCustomerNameUrdu + N' ' + @string + N' ' + sFatherNameUrdu from Customer
```

Comment: it gives me علی و سیعد but it should give me علی والد سیعد in out put

Comment: it is only printing first char in out put with concatination

Comment: sorry yes you need to give the variable a size still